# Sorting the sheets in a google sheets worksheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am reading data from google sheets, writing data to google sheets, and want to rearrange the sheets inside the worksheet:

```
CLIENT_SECRET_GOOGLE_SHEETS = r"client_secret_google_sheets.json"
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CLIENT_SECRET_GOOGLE_SHEETS, GSHEETS_SCOPES)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("my_worksheet")

worksheet_list = sheet.worksheets()
```

```
# worksheet_list 

[<Worksheet 'Documentation' id:35>,
 <Worksheet 'week 2' id:15>,
 <Worksheet 'week 1' id:20>]
```

I would like to change it to:

```
[<Worksheet 'Documentation' id:35>,
 <Worksheet 'week 1' id:20>,
 <Worksheet 'week 2' id:15>]
```

I tried searching for this functionality but was not able to find it in `gspread` documentation.

**UPDATE**

After using [Tanaike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) answer the order is not consistent:

```
[<Worksheet 'Documentation' id:35>,
 <Worksheet 'week 1' id:20>,
 <Worksheet 'week 10' id:150>,
 <Worksheet 'week 11' id:16>,
 <Worksheet 'week 2' id:115>,]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to realign the sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You don't want to include the 1st worksheet. You want to sort other sheets except for 1st tab by the sheet name.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this modification, the sheets except for the 1st tab are sorted by the batchUpdate method.

```py
client = ### # Please use your client in your script.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

# 1. Retrieve all sheets.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
sheets.pop(0)

# 2. Sort sheets except for 1st tab.
sortedSheets = sorted(sheets, key=lambda x: x.title)

# 3. Create request body.
requests = []
for i, sheet in enumerate(sortedSheets):
    requests.append({
        "updateSheetProperties": {
            "properties": {
                "index": i + 1,
                "sheetId": sheet.id
            },
            "fields": "index"
        }
    })

# 4. Request to Sheets API.
res = spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason the sheet order is the following `week 1, week 10, week 11, week 12 /13/14/15/16/17, week 2, week 3`. For some reason only the first number is taken in to account, do you know why?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I had supposed your sample value. When your sheet names are `week 1, week 10, week 11, week 12 /13/14/15/16/17, week 2, week 3`, how about modifying from `sortedSheets = sorted(sheets, key=lambda x: x.title)` to `sortedSheets = sorted(sheets, key=lambda x: int(x.title.split(' ')[1]))`? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up sorting the list myself as there are more rules, but the general `batch_update` for sorting sheets work, thank you!

Comment: would you be able to have a look at my most recent question regarding google sheets API as you are a professional in that?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis About `my most recent question`, if this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/71292680 ) is the question you want to resolve, it seems that your question has already been resolved. As another answer, in your script, you can modify `ws.update("HG3:HG5", [["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]])` to `ws.update("HG3", [["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]], major_dimension="COLUMNS")`. By this, those values are also put to the cells "HG3:HG5".