# Writing data to google sheets in a single column tries to write data to a column outside the determined range

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a google sheet in which I would like to add data to a certain range:

[image]

And to write the data I use:

```
ws = sheet.worksheet('test_sheet')
ws.update("HG3:HG5", [["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]])
```

But I can an error:

> APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Requested writing within range [test_sheet!HG3:HG5], but tried writing to column [HH]', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}

Why does it try to write to column `HH` if the range is clearly `HG3:HG5`? I do have a range that contains `3` cells and values inside `ws.update` also has `3` values. I tried using single brackets for `["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]` but that produces another error.

Where is my mistake? My goal is to be able to write values to a single column's range as in the image the values would become `"test_1", "test_2", "test_3"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The notation `[["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]]` writes into 3 columns of the same row
- To write into 3 rows of the same column, the notaiton should be
  `[["test_1"], ["test_2"], ["test_3"]]`

See [Writing to a single range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range).